# Unintended spaces and incorrect styling when migrating to new web host

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have spent one whole day but am not able to solve this issue for the life of me.

My source code worked fine in previous webhost, but when I changed the host my styling has gone awry. The browser(chrome+FF) interpret lot of unintended spaces. For instance my actual code:
[image]

when inspected in chrome looks like:
[image]

Also my css also gets jumbled up. For instance the two-width class comes as empty in inspect elements:
[image]

when it has been defined as

[image]

I tried themes with these two doctype/meta:
one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Two:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Will appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the files themselves? What do they look like? Are they fine locally? If not, can you just strip the whitespace and reupload them to your host?

Answer (score 0):

As Ian mentioned. it was an issue with whitespace.

Feel like banging my head against the wall for such an elementary oversight.

Thanks Ian.